# Is it allowed to use XPath function in atribute value

Tags: xslt, xpath

Is it possible to substitute the value of a tag attribute with XPath expression.
Namely:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:import href="../Product/templates.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template name="root" match="/">
        <test-report start="substring(abcd, 1, 2)" stop="2015-10-07 16:54.103">
            <xsl:call-template name="temp"/>
        </test-report>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="temp">
       <xsl:value-of select="'TEXT_RIKO'"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

The output is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <test-report start="substring(abcd, 1, 2)" stop="2015-10-07 16:54.103">
    TEXT_RIKO
 </test-report>
```

What I want is (in the output file) the value of the start attribute to be the output of the function **substring** namely `ab`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "Yes", but you need to use [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to do this.

Simply write this

```
<test-report start="{substring(abcd, 1, 2)}" stop="2015-10-07 16:54.103">
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated rather than output literally.